# google api: how attach the file to email, form drive?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, gmail

I find only this solution
https://ctrlq.org/code/20132-gmail-api-send-mail-attachments
but it's not effective - because the file download to local and then send it as attachment.

```
bytes: Utilities.base64Encode(file.getBlob().getBytes())
```

Answer (score 0):

See the sample provided in [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment),

> An attachment from Gmail. This is a regular [`Blob`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob) except that it
>   has an extra [`getSize()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment#getSize()) method that is faster than calling
>   [`getBytes()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment#getBytes()).length and does not count against the Gmail read
>   quota.

```
// Logs information about any attachments in the first 100 inbox threads.
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 100);
var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
for (var i = 0 ; i < msgs.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < msgs[i].length; j++) {
    var attachments = msgs[i][j].getAttachments();
    for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
      Logger.log('Message "%s" contains the attachment "%s" (%s bytes)',
                 msgs[i][j].getSubject(), attachments[k].getName(), attachments[k].getSize());
    }
  }
}
```

To learn more about Gmail API `Users.messages.attachments` methods, you can refer [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments).

Comment: what about your code? (you are reading the in-box messages, but i do not need read inpobx)
I needed send the email with attachment form google-sheets.
without the download sheet to my local server.
just attach to the new email the google-sheet by id.